# @Repository Not Being Autowired in @DataJpaTest with multiple @Configuration files being imported in one Configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have three @Configuration files, as follows:

MessageGatewayConfiguration.class

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
            "xyz.idtlabs.smsgateway.*"
})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
        AbstractPersistableCustom.class,
        SMSBridge.class,
        SMSBridgeConfig.class,
        SMSMessage.class,
        Tenant.class
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "xyz.idtlabs.smsgateway.*"
})
public class MessageGatewayConfiguration {  
    public MessageGatewayConfiguration() {
        super();
    } 
    @Bean
    public SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster applicationEventMulticaster() {
        final SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster multicaster = new SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster();
        multicaster.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        return multicaster;
    } 
    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryExceptionResolver();
    }     
}
```

SpringConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableMetrics
public class SpringConfiguringClass extends MetricsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureReporters(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        // registerReporter allows the MetricsConfigurerAdapter to
        // shut down the reporter when the Spring context is closed
        registerReporter(ConsoleReporter
            .forRegistry(metricRegistry)
            .build())
            .start(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

SmsFireboltConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@Import({ MessageGatewayConfiguration.class, SpringConfiguringClass.class })
public class SmsFireboltConfiguration { 
}
```

The main application file is as follows:

```
public class MessageGateway {

    public MessageGateway() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmsFireboltConfiguration.class, args);
    }
}
```

However, my Spring @DataJpaTest integration test is not autowiring the TenantRepository JPA repository, with a "No qualifying bean of type 'xyz.idtlabs.smsgateway.tenants.repository.TenantRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate" error. 
Its code is as follows:

```
@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MessageGateway.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = H2)
public class SmsMessageServiceIntegrationTest { 

    @Autowired
    private TenantRepository tenantRepository; 

      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
          tenantRepository.deleteAll();
      } 
    @Test
    //some test
}
```

Any possible idea on why this is? I have tried a number of combinations of setting up the @DataJpaTest file, but to no avail.

Comment: the TenantRepository class has an annotation @Repository right ?

Comment: please post the full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: yes @AmrAlaa , it does. And Jens Schauder, thanks for the help! I followed Sam Brenna's advise below and it fixed my issue. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specified a non-configuration class to `@ContextConfiguration`.

What you need is:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MessageGatewayConfiguration.class)
```

Or the following if you want to include all of your Spring config:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SmsFireboltConfiguration.class)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding either MessageGatewayConfiguration.class or SmsFireboltConfiguration.class to the @ContextConfiguration annotation fixed this.

Comment: Great! Glad that helped.  Mind _accepting_ the answer? ;)

Comment: You're very welcome, and thanks for accepting my answer!